# Linux FTP can't CD to anything before home directory

Tags: linux, ftp, home-directory

I've connected to my ftp server from my local linux terminal.

As far as I understand I've been using the `!` to navigate through local files (i.e `!ls` vs `ls`)

I can't seem to `cd ..` to my home folder, I'm trying to access /home/web but the farthest i can go is `to /home/my_user`

Can someone explain why and what I'd need to do to change this?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your ftp server is setup with CHROOT.  If you gave us some useful details like what FTP server you are using, maybe a config fragement, and or other details, we might actually be able to provide some useful help.

Comment: I think this is more of a linux question than a server question.. I might move this to a different stack

Comment: @iight  Or an FTP server/daemon question, not specific to Linux...

Comment: It is totally on topic.

Answer (score 5):

This is normal behaviour. Most of the FTP Server lock the user to their respective home directory to prevent access to other filesystem files. This is called "chroot", because you change the root directory of the this process.

In vsftp for example you can disable it by editing the configuration file `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` and change this value to no:

`chroot_local_user=no`